# ERROR collecting setup.py while trying to run py.test?

Tags: python, setuptools, pytest, tox

I am trying to run `py.test` on my package but it is trying to parse `setup.py` from the project root directory even if I tried to exclude it.

I need to collect the tests from *.py files because the test classes are included in the modules.

```
# setup.cfg
[pytest]
norecursedirs = .svn _build tmp* lib/third lib *.egg bin distutils setup.py
python_files = *.py
```

Still when I run `py.test` it will give me `ERROR collecting setup.py` which I already excluded.

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/distutils/core.py:140: in setup
>           raise SystemExit, gen_usage(dist.script_name) + "\nerror: %s" % msg
E           SystemExit: usage: py.test [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
E              or: py.test --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
E              or: py.test --help-commands
E              or: py.test cmd --help
E           
E           error: no commands supplied
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can configure the --ignore option to your pytest.ini configuration like this maybe:

```
addopts = --ignore=setup.py
```

which should help if you are in the root directory and want py.test to ignore the setup.py file.

Comment: Damn, it means that if I have another `setup.py` it will also be included. Also, tox is not able to look for tox.ini in the parent directories?!

Comment: To avoid other setup.py files being included i think pytest.ini would need a way to allow specifying exact locations like --ignore={inidir}/setup.py or so.

Answer (score 2):

From the docs (and the name of the variable) it looks like `norecursedirs` only skips directories, so since `setup.py` is a file, putting it in `norecursedirs` has no effect.

http://pytest.org/latest/customize.html?highlight=norecursedirs#confval-norecursedirs

Comment: Thanks, for remarking it. Still this doesn't solve my problem. From these I would assume that it's impossible to prevent `py.test` from loading `setup.py` if you want to look for `*.py`. Still the error appears because `py.test` is trying to execute `setup.py`. Maybe there is something I can do with setup.py to make it `py.test` friendly.

Answer (score 2):

The pytest docs have the answer buried away [here.](https://pytest.org/latest/example/pythoncollection.html#customizing-test-collection-to-find-all-py-files) Put a `conftest.py` file in the root directory of your project that lists the files you want `pytest` to ignore:

> However, many projects will have a setup.py which they don’t want to be imported. Moreover, there may files only importable by a specific python version. For such cases you can dynamically define files to be ignored by listing them in a conftest.py file:
>
> ---
>
> ```
>  # content of conftest.py
>  import sys
>
>  collect_ignore = ["setup.py"]
> ```
>
> ---

Answer (score 1):

In [Jedi](https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi) we've solved this by adding a `conftest.py` file with the content of `collect_ignore = ["setup.py"]`. That makes it "magically" work.

IMHO py.test should make it easier to ignore `setup.py`, because that's a very typical use case.